How to print the full, updated array after removing the last object?
I'm currently making a website with a "shopping list" functionality. I can create an array and add items to the "shopping list" via the input field, and I can also remove the latest input using a button.
As of now, the list shows all new items in order of input. But, when I remove the latest item, it shows only that item. And then when I add a new item, the full, updated list shows.
These pictures show how it currently looks:

Add items, that show up in the list ¨

Remove item - the list disappears and only the latest item being removed is shown

The new, updated list shows ONLY after I've added a new item to the list ("four")


What I'm trying to do is this:

Add items - they show up in the list, as now

Remove item - the latest item is just removed from the list, but the list still shows previous items remaining. The picture here is how I want it to look.



Add new items again - they get added to the list in order of input as it looks in the picture.




var arrayOfWord = [];
var inputElement = document.getElementById('userinput');
var errorElement = document.getElementById('error');
var wordsElement = document.getElementById('words');

function addWord() {
  errorElement.innerHTML = "";
  var word = inputElement.value;
  if (word.trim() === "")
    errorElement.innerHTML = "Empty input, write an item you want to put on the list!";
  else
    arrayOfWord.push(word);
  inputElement.value = "";
  process();
}

function process() {
  words.innerHTML = arrayOfWord.join(' <br><br> ');
}

function remove() {
  words.innerHTML = arrayOfWord.pop();
  document.getElementById('words').innerHTML = parsed;
}
<p>
  <ol id="demo"></ol>
</p>

<input id="userinput" /><button onclick="addWord()">Add item</button>
<div id="error"></div>
<button onclick="remove()">Remove</button><br>

<p id="testing"></p>
<p id="words"></p><br>

<a href="#" class="action">Buy Now</a>
</div>




As pointed out in the console: "ReferenceError: parsed is not defined"

Your variables naming is weird ! Look in the process function you call innerHTML on words which is not defined in this code.
Same in remove function and in this function you also re do a document.getElementById instead of using the defined variable wordsElement.

The issue is because of this line in remove():
words.innerHTML = arrayOfWord.pop();

That is removing the last item from the array, but it then sets that item, which has been removed from your array, as the visible text within the element.
To fix the problem call pop() without setting the HTML of the element directly, then call your process() function to update the DOM based on the
new content of the array:
function remove() {
  arrayOfWord.pop();
  process();
}

Here's a full working example:


var arrayOfWord = [];
var inputElement = document.getElementById('userinput');
var errorElement = document.getElementById('error');
var wordsElement = document.getElementById('words');

function addWord() {
  errorElement.innerHTML = "";
  var word = inputElement.value;
  if (word.trim() === "")
    errorElement.innerHTML = "Empty input, write an item you want to put on the list!";
  else
    arrayOfWord.push(word);
  inputElement.value = "";
  process();
}

function process() {
  words.innerHTML = arrayOfWord.join(' <br><br> ');
}

function remove() {
  arrayOfWord.pop();
  process();
}
<p>
  <ol id="demo"></ol>
</p>
<input id="userinput" /><button onclick="addWord()">Add item</button>
<div id="error"></div>
<button onclick="remove()">Remove</button><br>

<p id="testing"></p>
<p id="words"></p><br>

<a href="#" class="action">Buy Now</a>
</div>



Also, as a side note, be aware that ol elements are not valid within p (further reading on this here), and it's much better practice to bind your event handlers unobtrusively in JS using addEventListener() instead of using onX attributes in your HTML.

It is generally not a good idea to use inline event handlers. Furthermore, I'd say the interface is not so clear. How would a user know what the remove button does? Wouldn't it be an idea to enable removing one of all items instead of the last added?
With that in mind I suggest something like this (using event delegation and a factory function for the handling):


document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
document.addEventListener(`keyup`, handle);
const actions = actionFactory();

function handle(evt) {
  const action = evt.target.dataset.action;
  
  if (action && action in actions) {
    return actions[action](evt);
  }
}

function actionFactory() {
  const addBttn = document.querySelector(`[data-action='add']`);
  const userInput = document.querySelector(`#userinput`);
  const errorElem = document.querySelector(`#error`);
  const words = document.querySelector(`#words`);
  let selectedWords = [];
  
  return {
    enter: function(evt) {
      if(evt.key === 'Enter') {
        return addBttn.click();
      }
    },
    add: function() {
      const inputValue = userInput.value.trim();
      
      if (inputValue.length < 1) {
        errorElem.textContent = "please fill out with some text";
        return setTimeout(_ => errorElem.textContent = ``, 2000);
      }
      
      selectedWords.push(inputValue);
      // add the word to the words-element
      words.insertAdjacentHTML(
      `beforeend`,
      `<div>
         <span>${inputValue}</span> 
         <button data-action="remove">remove</button>
       </div>`);
      return userInput.value = ``;
    },
    remove: function(evt) {
      const wordElem = evt.target.closest(`div`);
      const word = wordElem.querySelector(`span`).textContent;
      // re-assign the array, filtering out the word to remove
      selectedWords = selectedWords.filter(wrd => wrd !== word);
      return wordElem.remove();
    }
  }
}
#error {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
  color: red;
}

#words {
  div {
    margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  }
  div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #EEE;
  }
  div > span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 177px;
  }
}
<input id="userinput" 
  placeholder="type something" 
  data-action="enter">
<button data-action="add">Add item</button>
<span id="error"></span>
<p id="words"></p>




The problem you are facing is most probably because of arrayOfWord.pop() method in function remove.  You are assigning the value of arrayOfWord.pop() to words.innerHTML , which eventually returns the deleted element not the the whole array.
To fix this issue you can think of another approach like re rendering the whole array as updated result
Use pop method but don't render it to your page .  Hope this will work for you
